# Using variables in PrometheusRule expr field instead of contant values

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql, prometheus-operator, kube-prometheus-stack

I am trying to create a 'PrometheusRule' inside my cluster with some alert rules using `promql` expressions. However, I want these resources to be used and configurable for different services inside my same cluster. All I want to do is have Variable values inside my "expr" field, something like this:

```
expr: sum( nginx_ingress_controller_requests{status=~"5.+"} ) > VARIABLE_VALUE
```

Instead of:

```
expr: sum( nginx_ingress_controller_requests{status=~"5.+"} ) > 50
```

This is the `PromethuesRule` I am trying to make:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  name: blablaname
  namespace: blablans
spec:
  groups:
  - name: {{ include "blabla.fullname" . }}-cache
    rules:
    - alert: TOOMANY5XXX
      annotations:
        description: too many 5XXs
        summary: blablabla
      expr: sum( nginx_ingress_controller_requests{status=~"5.+"} ) > VARIABLE_VALUE
      for: 5m
      labels:
        severity: critical
```

PS: I am using Helm charts as my package manager and would like the Variable to be present in my `Values.yaml` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using helm then use simple variable assignment:

```
expr: sum( nginx_ingress_controller_requests{status=~"5.+"} ) > {{ .Values.VariableValue }}
```